# Do my troops recover fully after each battle?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

For the heroes in my band, their health will not completely recover after a battle, how about my troops? Will their health recover 100% after each battle?

If their health do not recover, how do I know how much hit point they have left?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Troops that are not killed or knocked unconscious enter the next battle at a maximum health.
Only yourself, heroes and NPC commanders have health outside of each battle.

However if a troop is knocked unconscious, they will take some time before they are battle ready again (thus you may see your party as being 23/25 due to troops who are unable to fight)